# Locked out of EC2 ubuntu instance because of /home perms

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I was showing my kids some basic things about directory permissions on an EC2 ubuntu instance, and did this

```
$ sudo chmod 700 /home
```

Then demonstrated that I could no longer `cd` to my home directory because permission was denied.

Then I **inadvertantly** disconnected from the EC2 instance.  Now I cannot log back in because the sshd on the ubuntu side cannot access my `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  I've tried to think about workarounds, but I'm out of ideas.

I am prepared to delete and recreate the entire instance, but would much rather salvage this one if possible.  Any ideas?!

Comment: Create a new instance, mount the EBS instance as a data disk, change permissions.

Comment: @Tim You might want to turn this into an answer

Comment: With that suggestion Fixee can work it out and post an answer.

Comment: I'm an experienced *nix admin, but new to EC2.  It took me about 30mins to figure out (aka google) the steps Tim outlined above, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Tim's suggestion:

I clicked `Launch Instance` to create a new instance.  I just took whatever the first AMI was listed (some Amazon version of Linux) and created it with defaults, using a keypair I had already on hand.

I then clicked on `Volumes` and detached the EBS volume from my hosed machine.  This took about 30 secs.  Then I selected `Attach Volume` and I attached it to the new instance as `/dev/sdf`.  Then I `ssh`ed into the new instance.

In the new instance I typed

```
$ sudo mkdir /caribou
$ sudo mount /dev/sdf1 /caribou
$ cd /caribou
$ sudo chmod 755 home
```

That repaired the `/home` dir permissions.

I then went back to the EC2 console, detached the EBS volume from the Amazon instance and re-attached it to my original Ubuntu instance as `/dev/sda1`.  Then I started the old instance and logged in, with everything fixed.

Took 30 mins including time to figure out all of the above.  Thanks to Tim.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post how you fixed it, instead of just moving on.

Comment: Welcome. I figured with that little tip you'd work it out, and I didn't have time to write a full answer.

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if EC2 has this option (it should), but if you haven't disabled root login completely, then open a console session on your instance through EC2 website, log in as root, restore readable permissions and you should be fine.

Comment: I searched around but cannot find a way to login to my EC2 instance as root.